# Ansible - How to keep appending new keys to a dictionary when using set_fact module with with_items?

Tags: ansible

I want to add keys to a dictionary when using set_fact with with_items. This is a small POC which will help me complete some other work. I have tried to generalize the POC so as to remove all the irrelevant details from it.

When I execute following code it is shows a dictionary with only one key that corresponds to the last item of the with_items. It seems that it is re-creating a new dictionary or may be overriding an existing dictionary for every item in the with_items. I want a single dictionary with all the keys.

Code:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
      some_value: 12345
      dict: {}
  tasks:
     - set_fact: {
          dict: "{
             {{ item }}: {{ some_value }}
             }"
            }
       with_items:
          - 1
          - 2
          - 3
     - debug: msg="{{ dict }}"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [filter plugin](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#filter-plugins).

First, make a new file in your ansible base dir called `filter_plugins/makedict.py`.

Now create a new function called "makedict" (or whatever you want) that takes a value and a list and returns a new dictionary where the keys are the elements of the list and the value is always the same.

```
class FilterModule(object):
     def filters(self):
         return { 'makedict': lambda _val, _list: { k: _val for k in _list }  }
```

Now you can use the new filter in the playbook to achieve your desired result:

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  vars:
      my_value: 12345
      my_keys: [1, 2, 3]
  tasks:
    - set_fact: my_dict="{{ my_value | makedict(my_keys) }}"
    - debug: msg="{{ item.key }}={{ item.value }}"
      with_dict: "{{my_dict}}"
```

You can [customize the location](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#filter-plugins) of the filter plugin using the `filter_plugins` option in `ansible.cfg`.

Answer (score 56):

This can also be done without resorting to plugins, tested in Ansible 2.2.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    some_value: 12345
    dict: {}
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      dict: "{{ dict | combine( { item: some_value } ) }}"
    with_items:
      - 1
      - 2
      - 3
  - debug: msg="{{ dict }}"
```

Alternatively, this can be written without the complex one-liner with an include file.

```yaml
  tasks:
  - include: append_dict.yml
    with_items: [1, 2, 3]
```

append_dict.yml:

```yaml
- name: "Append dict: define helper variable"
  set_fact:
    _append_dict: "{ '{{ item }}': {{ some_value }} }"

- name: "Append dict: execute append"
  set_fact:
    dict: "{{ dict | combine( _append_dict ) }}"
```

Output:

```
TASK [debug]
*******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "1": "12345",
        "2": "12345",
        "3": "12345"
    }
}
```

Single quotes `'` around `{{ some_value }}` are needed to store string values explicitly.

This syntax can also be used to append from a `dict` elementwise using `with_dict` by referring to `item.key` and `item.value`.

Manipulations like adding pre- and postfixes or hashes can be performed in the same step, for example

```yaml
    set_fact:
      dict: "{{ dict | combine( { item.key + key_postfix: item.value + '_' +  item.value | hash('md5') } ) }}"
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for loop variables when looping over an `includes`

Comment: You could use `dict: "{{ dict | default({}) | combine( { item: some_value } ) }}"` to not have to initialize it to an empty dict.

Answer (score 0):

this does not seems to work any more on ansible 2.5

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    some_value: 12345
    dict: {}
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      dict: "{{ dict | combine( { item: some_value } ) }}"
    with_items:
      - 1
      - 2
      - 3
  - debug: msg="{{ dict }}"
```

returns only last value `{"dict":{"3": "some value"}}`

I suggest you could do this :

```
- set_fact:
    __dict: |
        {% for item in  [1,2,3] %}
        {{item}}: "value"
        {% endfor %}

- set_fact:
    final_dict: "{{__dict|from_yaml}}"

- debug: 
  var: final_dict
```

Comment: Please reference the relevant bug report: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/39452 - this was a bug that has already been fixed in Ansible 2.5.2.

Comment: I am downvoting this because the bug has been fixed, so this answer only provides an alternative way of doing it which in my opinion is worse than the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be this one, tested in Ansible 2.9.6.

This solutions adds the extra benefit that you do not have to declare `_dict` beforehand in `vars` section. This is achieved by the `| default({})` pipe which ensures that the loop will not fail in the first iteration when `_dict` is empty.

In addition, the renaming of `dict` to `_dict` is necessary since the `dict` is a special keyword reserved for `<class 'dict'>`. Referenced (unfortunately only at devel branch yet) [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names).

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    some_value: 12345
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      _dict: "{{ _dict | default({}) | combine( { item: some_value } ) }}"
    with_items:
      - 1
      - 2
      - 3
  - debug: msg="{{ _dict }}"
```